# <select> não funciona Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Bom dia Galera, fiz uma busca com Ajax usando "input". Agora preciso fazer a mesma forma de pesquisa, mas invés de ser um "input", tenho que usar um "select". Já testei usando como input e funcionou. Mas usando "select" não. O que será que está errado?

```html
<div id="content">
        <div id="result">
            <TABLE>
                #TBODY#
            </TABLE>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="busca">
            <select id="option" name="option">
                                <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
                                <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
                                <option value="3">Março</option>
                                <option value="4">Abril</option>
                                <option value="5">Maio</option>
                                <option value="6">Junho</option>
                                <option value="7">Julho</option>
                                <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                                <option value="9">Setembro</option>
                                <option value="10">Outubro</option>
                                <option value="11">Novembro</option>
                                <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
                            </select>

        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#option').keyup(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        $.post(url + 'Ajax/showmes', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
            $('#result').html(busca);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que o evento correto seria o `change`, no `keyup` ele detecta a tecla. O change ele é acionado quando o elemento obtêm um valor diferente, então quando o usuário escolher outra opção ele será acionado.

O `keyup` funcionou no caso do input porque ele recebe entrada de texto

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#option').change(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        $.post(url + 'Ajax/showmes', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
            $('#result').html(busca);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo. Muito obrigado.